# is there a way to replace all curly braces in a string with parentheses in python?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project that involves strings that contain curly braces, but I would like to replace the curly braces with parentheses. I've tried using the .replace() function, but it doesn't seem to recognize curly braces as normal characters.

An example of the string I am getting would be the below:

> {AttributeToModify=AttributeDefinition'D_Attributes.Weapon.WeaponClipSize',ModifierType=MT_Scale,BaseModifierValue={BaseValueConstant=2.000000,BaseValueAttribute=None,InitializationDefinition=None,BaseValueScaleConstant=1.000000}}

And the desired result would be the following:

> (AttributeToModify=AttributeDefinition'D_Attributes.Weapon.WeaponClipSize',ModifierType=MT_Scale,BaseModifierValue=(BaseValueConstant=2.000000,BaseValueAttribute=None,InitializationDefinition=None,BaseValueScaleConstant=1.000000))

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's worked.

```py
a = "{AttributeToModify=AttributeDefinition'D_Attributes.Weapon.WeaponClipSize',ModifierType=MT_Scale,BaseModifierValue={BaseValueConstant=2.000000,BaseValueAttribute=None,InitializationDefinition=None,BaseValueScaleConstant=1.000000}}"
print(a.replace("{", "(").replace("}", ")"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace function makes it possible. This should work :

```
 st = "{AttributeToModify=AttributeDefinition'D_Attributes.Weapon.WeaponClipSize',ModifierType=MT_Scale,BaseModifierValue={BaseValueConstant=2.000000,BaseValueAttribute=None,InitializationDefinition=None,BaseValueScaleConstant=1.000000}}"
print(st)

print(st.replace("{","(").replace("}",")"))
```

Output is :

```
{AttributeToModify=AttributeDefinition'D_Attributes.Weapon.WeaponClipSize',ModifierType=MT_Scale,BaseModifierValue={BaseValueConstant=2.000000,BaseValueAttribute=None,InitializationDefinition=None,BaseValueScaleConstant=1.000000}}
(AttributeToModify=AttributeDefinition'D_Attributes.Weapon.WeaponClipSize',ModifierType=MT_Scale,BaseModifierValue=(BaseValueConstant=2.000000,BaseValueAttribute=None,InitializationDefinition=None,BaseValueScaleConstant=1.000000))
```